# Growing white space on right side of page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've got a responsive website template that I converted to an ASP.NET MVC app that seems to have some strange behavior when making the browser window smaller.  As I shrink the window's width and get below 986 pixels, this white "space" appears to the right of the content and continues to grow as the window gets smaller (see red zig-zag in pic)
[image]

The site is [www.prophysique.com](http://www.prophysique.com) if you want to have a look at it in real time.  I've tried to use some of the developer tools to see where the space is coming from but can't seem to track down the issue.  Can anyone make any suggestions as to what I can try to figure out where this space is being generated from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit:** Your FB widget is the other element causing an issue. It's got a set width that makes it expand beyond your content box.

`.caption_style1` has `width: 1170px` set on it. Taking that off reduces some of that space - there's some crazy padding and margin on the h4 inside of that also, but that doesn't seem to reduce the space for me.

There's got to be another element somewhere in your code with an explicit width set that's greater than the browser window when it's under 986px.

The whitespace shows up because the elements with background colors specified are 100%, so if the window has a scroll bar (due to an element inside one of those elements having a width greater than the window width), that color doesn't extend into the scrollable area.

Comment: good catch on the `.caption.style1`...as you said, it seems to have helped a bit but there's still some there.  What do you mean by your last paragraph?  I'm not too sure what you are trying to explain there.

Comment: The space to the right when you scroll appears because there is an element on your page, contained within another element, that has a specific width set on it (like the one I found). I've run into this on a site before, and I had to look at every element on the page because it was hidden within another element. Because the outer elements (like `header`) are set to `width: 100%`, you don't see the div expand to accommodate that inner element with a specific width set.

Comment: I noticed the FB widget before I posted this question and changed it, however, I didn't upload it to the live site just yet.  At any rate, you were right, there was some passing in the footer that was causing the extension like that.  I'm still working on it but it appears to have fixed it 99%.  Thanks again!